# Why is default Geometry node called Group Input and Group Output?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Brand new to Blender and geometry nodes so I apologize if this is a silly / basic question. I was going through the manual for geometry nodes to try to better understand what's really happening behind the scenes with each one.

Just curious why the default nodes are called Group Input and Group Output. What 'Group's are they referring to?

Feel free to point me to a section of the manual I missed if this should be obvious based on documentation for those nodes somewhere that I couldn't find!

Thanks a lot,
Billy

Comment: I think you can actually use group input to basically add parameters to the modifier panel for you to adjust as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'group' in this case is the entire node tree you create when you set up a geometry node modifier.  The names are patterned on the exit and entry nodes for a 'node group' that you can create in the existing node systems for materials and the compositor.  If I select some nodes in a material and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>G</kbd> to group them, Blender adds two nodes to the group, here outlined in red boxes:

[image: Simple node group showing the group input and group output nodes]

I can connect noodles to inputs inside the group from the *Group Input*, for example, and when I use the group, they show up thusly:

[image: adding inputs]

[image: The resulting group, showing the inputs]

When I add a *Geometry Nodes* Modifier to an object, something similar is created. Instead of showing up as a group with a input though, this overall group shows up in the modifier:

[image: Input noodle added for size]

[image: size showing up in the modifier]

Since they serve a similar purpose they were given the same names.